# Android to Mysql database connection using django rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

What should i give in URL in android side .java file  to connect with my django REST API and code for django to get data through POST?

Answer (score 0):

in DRF:

project/project/setting.py:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'xxx',
    'USER': 'your_account',
    'PASSWORD': 'your_password',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'POST': '3306',
}
```

}

project/project/__init.py

(you need to install pymysql model by:pip install pymysql)

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

project/you_app/view.py

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = ProductSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            product= serializer.create(serializer.validated_data)
        return Response(data='success', status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    @list_route(methods=['POST'])
    def search(self, request):
        key = request.data['key']
        queryset = Product.objects.filter(name__icontains=key)
        serializer = ProductSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

project/project/url.py

```
from rest_framework import routers

from user.views import UserViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register(r'product', ProductViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
urlpatterns += router.urls
```

in Android Okhttp3 demo:

```
    RequestBody requestBody = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("key", ProductName)
            .build();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .post(requestBody)
            .url(Constants.ProductSearch)
            .build();

    HttpClientUtil.getClient().newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {}

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
            final String data = response.body().string();
            Log.e("Http",data);
        }
    });
```

Comment: URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:8000");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

Comment: what should be URL in android code to connect with my django rest code?
I have my POST code in views.py

Comment: not 127.0.0.1:8000,url is something like 192.168.1.xxx,you can look you server ip address on windows cmd by ipconfig(ifconfig on linux)，url.py has update,have a look。

Comment: my django server is running on http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin ,and my android app is running on android emulator on same machine,my POST code is on views.py,so in android what url should i provide 192.168.56.1,is not working,i tried

Comment: you need a real android device,or install an android app to ping your machine.runserver on 192.168.56.1:8000 and android url as same.

Comment: My android to mysql on same machine is possible using PHP script in backend ,so it should work with django also using emulator.